# Auto-complete C/C++ functions

Tags: auto-complete-mode, c

I want code completion for C/C++ functions and variables from headers. I tried to install Auto-complete and Company, but C/C ++ functions/variables aren't complemented.

Here is the relevant portion of my `.emacs` file:

```el
;; Auto-complete (AC)
(require 'auto-complete)

(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
```

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your init file that shows how you are using `auto-complete` and/or `company`.

Comment: I'm using https://gist.github.com/soonhokong/7c2bf6e8b72dbc71c93b and https://www.gnu.org/software/global/ which works decently for the relatively small projects that I have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A vanilla company install wont quite get you where you want; you'll need to use use something like the `company-c-headers` package. Tuhdo has written an [excellent document](http://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html) on using Emacs as a C/C++ IDE, which has instructions on setting up `company-c-headers`, along with a lot of other stuff.

I don't know what Emacs version you're using, but in 24.5 with Company, you'd do something like this:

1. Install the `company-c-headers` package from MELPA -- `M-x package-install company-c-headers`
2. Add this to your emacs config file (`init.el` / `.emacs.d` / whathaveyou)

   ```lisp
   (require 'company)
   (add-hook 'global-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
   (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-c-headers)
   ```

Note that `company-c-headers` by default only searches two paths for headers. If you want it to search others, you'll need to add them yourself. (For more on that, see [Tuhdo](http://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html#orgheadline16))